# How to provide global environment variables to AWS SAM local

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

When running sams locally to test my api gateway and passing environment variables, I can run the command

```
sam local start-api -n env-vars.json
```

This works well when the environment variables are tied to a specific function like this

```
MyFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: index.handler
    Runtime: nodejs8.10
    CodeUri: .
    Environment:
      Variables:
        FIRST_BUCKET: !Ref firstBucket
        SECOND_BUCKET: !Ref secondBucket
```

However, I currently have global enviroment variables like this

```
Globals:
  Function:
    CodeUri: .
    Runtime: nodejs8.10
    Environment:
      Variables:
        FIRST_BUCKET: !Ref firstBucket
        SECOND_BUCKET: !Ref secondBucket
```

How can I pass custom global environment variables to SAMS using `env-var.json`?
I'd expect to be able to do something like this for my `env-var.json` file

```
{
  "Globals": {
    "Function": {
      "FIRST_BUCKET": "this-is-my-bucket-name"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and I can not find any resources online showing the correct syntax to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I will have to test this tomorrow, but reading through the [transform documentation](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst) (and what I understand of the SAM transform) I expect the global variables are just applied to each function without having to re-state them.

So you will form your env.json as normal for each function:
e.g.,

```
{
  "MyFunction": {
      "FIRST_BUCKET": "this-is-my-bucket-name"
  },
  "MySecondFunction": {
      "SECOND_BUCKET": "this-is-my-second-bucket-name"
  }
}
```

This will result in your lambda functions having both globals, but only overwriting the passed value:

MyFunction:

- FIRST_BUCKET = "this-is-my-bucket-name"
- SECOND_BUCKET = !Ref secondBucket

MySecondFunction:

- FIRST_BUCKET = !Ref firstBucket
- SECOND_BUCKET = "this-is-my-second-bucket-name"

Remember, your function will have both variables used in your function, but you are only overwriting the variable you are passing from json.